# How to make input box show the options that match with the beginning of the user's input using html datalist?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, input, html-datalist

I am new to React and want to implement an autocomplete suggestion box for a text input box that matches only the first letters of the options available and not just any substring which is the current behaviour of HTML's `<datalist>`.

I have found great answers in jQuery achieving exactly the behaviour that I need. I am just having a hard time finding a way I can achieve this behaviour using React syntax.

Here are the jQuery solutions I have found so far.

[How to make datalist match result from beginning only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592978/how-to-make-datalist-match-result-from-beginning-only)

[HTML5 Datalist auto suggest shows the list that starts with the search keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111844/html5-datalist-auto-suggest-shows-the-list-that-starts-with-the-search-keyword)

Here is my current code structure:

```
<div className="form-field word-field">
      <label>Word</label>
      <Field list="word_list" id="word" name="word" />
       {errors.word && touched.word && <div className="validation-error">{errors.word}</div>}
      <datalist id="word_list">
         <option>Arc</option>
         <option>House</option>
         <option>Handle</option>
         <option>Chair</option>
         <option>Door</option>
      </datalist>
</div>
```

Can I be given any pointers on how to achieve this? What should I look into to get the behaviour I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a simple component that does this with datalist:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const initialOptionsArr = [
  "India",
  "United States",
  "United Kingdom",
  "Germany",
  "France",
  "Israel"
];
export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(initialOptionsArr);

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    if (target.value) {
      const filteredOptions = initialOptionsArr.filter((option) =>
        option.toLowerCase().startsWith(target.value.toLowerCase())
      );
      setOptions(filteredOptions);
    } else {
      setOptions(initialOptionsArr);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        list="countries"
        name="mycountry"
        id="countryInput"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      <datalist id="countries">
        {options.map((item) => (
          <option value={item}>{item}</option>
        ))}
      </datalist>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code uses useState hook and is pretty simple. Please let me know if this helps you. Here is a sandbox link of above: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hodgkin-7lsu5v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! I used your answer as a base to achieve the solution I needed